# XamlParseException: Cannot assign property "Content": type mismatch between "System.String" and "Xamarin.Forms.View"

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm currently studying modules about Xamarin and try some of the sample code:

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Modul2" 
             x:Class="Modul2.MainPage"> 
  <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"> 
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="1000"> 
      <Label Text="Practice 2.1"  FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="Center"/> 
      <Label x:Name="lblDetail" Text="This Label is use to show the details" 
        FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/> 
      <Button x:Name="btnHello" Text="Hello Button" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
          VerticalOptions="Fill" /> 
      <Entry x:Name="entryHello" Placeholder="Username" VerticalOptions="Center" 
        Keyboard="Text"/> 
      <Image x:Name="helloImg" Source="icon.png" Aspect="AspectFit" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill"/> 
    </StackLayout> 
  </ScrollView> 
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
    { 
        public MainPage() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            btnHello.Clicked += BtnHello_Clicked; 
        } 
 
        private void BtnHello_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            lblDetail.Text = entryHello.Text; 
        } 
    }
```

but when I run the code using android emulator it show an error that say:

**Unhandled Exception:
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Cannot assign property "Content": type mismatch between "System.String" and "Xamarin.Forms.View"**

can anybody help???

Comment: Which line it is throwing that exception?